# How can I change the font of the row numbers? (listings package)

Tags: formatting, listings, typewriter

Is there a way to make the row numbers on the left of the code the same font as the code? I believe if you change the default font of the code, the row numbers are still in the default font. I'm using the `listings` package and changed to the Deja Vu Sans Mono font.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=tb,
aboveskip=3mm,
belowskip=3mm,
showstringspaces=false,
columns=flexible,
basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
numbers=left,
numbersep=0pt,
numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    Hello
    Hello
    Hello
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\ttfamily` to your settings for `\numberstyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=1ex,
  numberstyle={\tiny\color{gray}\ttfamily},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Hello
Hello
Hello
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```